# The sudden arrest

Tags: riddle

A man kills his wife and then hides the body in some bushes. The next morning the police find the body and interogate the killer:


Policeman:Where where you at the time of the murder?
Killer: At the pub.

The killer is arrested immediately. Why?

Comment: Is this a riddle you came up with? If not, please give credit to the source. If it is, well done! It is a bit broad (It can have many answers that could be correct) but I personally like broad riddles :)

Comment: It is a riddle from Riddles.fyi (https://riddles.fyi/a-man-kills-his-wife-and-hides-the-body-in-some-bushes-the-next-day-the-police-call-and-say-his-wife-has-been-murdered-and-tell-the-man-to-come-to-the-crime-scene-right-away-as-soon-as-the-man-gets/) that I have adapted.

Comment: Surely, they interrogated a 'suspect'

Comment: @Strawberry They interrogated a suspect who was the killer. It is just a lot easier to write killer

Comment: It's a bit of a giveaway though

Comment: It's the fact that the killer was arrested not that the police solved a crime

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess because

> They asked the killer where he was at the time of the murder, but they haven't specified the time. Everyone but the killer would first ask what time they mean.

or

> They "interogated the killer", which means they already knew it was him

Comment: your first answer is correct

Comment: @WilliamPennanti nice, btw you can mark an answer as accepted when it's correct

Comment: I know. I have a time limit though so will have to wait 5 mins

Comment: you can also wait a bit to encourage more answers to be posted. You don't have to though.

Comment: Unfortunately the suspect could have been the janitor at the pub and so really could have been on his way home on encountering the murder scene.

Comment: It's also perfectly plausible that when he left for the pub, his wife was alive, and when he got back, she was dead. Seems a bit of a jump to go and arrest him...

Comment: @Persona It says that the police found the body.

Comment: @Persona, if you take a look at the first answer by Ian Fako, you see the correct one.

Answer (score 7):

A light-hearted option...

> Because the policeman had been at the pub!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because

> the man is the owner of said pub and lives there. The body was found in the bushes around the pub, therefore the man is essentially saying that he was exactly where the murder happened.

Comment: that is a very good ideea and would be correct. It isn't the one that I thought of but yes, that would be acceptable. Well done

Comment: If there are multiple answers, doesn't that make ur question too broad? (Broad questions are not good :) ) @WilliamPennanti

Comment: To me riddles can have more than one acceptable answer as long as there aren't hundreds. With every riddle, i'm sure there are loopholes meaning more than one answer.

Comment: @WilliamPennanti One or two really well-fit answers is fine. It's when you get many unintended answers where there's really nothing that rules them out that you've got a riddle that's too broad. I think this one is the latter; there are too many plausible explanations, and not nearly enough in the riddle that would rule them out.

Comment: @Rubio Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

> the murder took place in India and the date was October 2nd, the birth date of Gandhiji. All pubs in the country will be closed on that day and so the police arrested the killer immediately, understanding that he is lying.

Comment: That is a bit of a broad one

Answer (score 1):

> The killer was a security guard somewhere, he was suposed to be working at the time of the crime, but he confesed he was not. He was elsewhere killing the wife.